# Laravel 5.7 add comments to database

Tags: php, laravel

I am following tutorial for creating forum in Laravel and I am currently at posts replies so I can add them to the database.

I have this function in ForumController.php

```
public function postReply(CreateReplyRequest $request) {

    $post =  Post::where('slug', '=', $request['slug'])->first();

    if( $post ) {
        $reply = new Reply;

        $reply->post_id = $post->id;
        $reply->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $reply->text = $request['text'];

        $reply->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

It is only returning me back to homepage (/) and not adding any reply to database. I do not know where can be error. Thanks for help.

Comment: It looks like `$post` is empty. Are you sure there is a post that has the same slug as `$request['slug']`? What happens when you dump the slug from the request?

Comment: Can you please help me, what to write to see the dump? I am not very skilled in this, I am learning. Thank you.

Comment: The controller code looks fine. You just need to make sure your form (or API request, etc) is passing the data properly.

Comment: You had the dump here a second ago. It's not a problem with the controller, it's a problem with the data you are passing in.

Comment: I think I know what is wrong. In my blade file, where is form action, I need to write there some hidden input to get `$post->slug` value. Can you help me with that? Thanks

Comment: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers. I had to install Form package from Laravel Collective via Composer. I had to pass the slug via `{!! Form::hidden('slug', $post->slug) !!}`. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public function postReply(CreateReplyRequest $request) {

    $post =  Post::where('slug', $request['slug'])->first();

    if( $post != null) {
        $reply = new Reply;

        $reply->post_id = $post->id;
        $reply->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $reply->text = $request['text'];

        $reply->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Or, rewrite your code to use ID instead of slug and post with a hidden input if you want to tell it what type to use

Comment: This did not help, I think that there can be problem with slug. Thanks for help.